# Why would this AND gate not work?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, basic

Why would this circuit not work as it is expected to work? The IC used in this is  a 7408 AND gate.

[image: AND Gate Circuit]

Comment: What does "not work" mean? i.e. what behaviour is it exhibiting that is not what it should be doing.

Comment: What is the value of the resistor?

Comment: You need at least 1 bypass capacitor from Vcc to ground pins or it may just sit and oscillate.

Comment: The resistor is 220 ohms, but would that really make any difference as long as the resistor is low enough to allow the LED to turn on and high enough to prevent it from fusing. @HarrySvensson

Comment: Right, so it's a homework question. Not something you are trying to wire up.

Comment: that was quick.

Comment: Woaw, interesting. I am speechless for everything that just unfolded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are missing pull downs on the input switches. The parasitic capacitance at the gate will be charged but never discharged. Though this greatly depends on what kind of transistors and what topology that has been used.

The other gates should have their input tied to VDD or ground to make sure that they are not oscillating.

The resistor in series with the LED should not be too low, those chips can't really source that much. I'd go with a 1 kΩ resistor if I were you.

Answer (score 5):

You haven't explained what "not work as expected" means, so we can only guess at mistakes.

Here are some suggestions:

1. If it is a CMOS 7408, you are missing pull-down resistors on the inputs. When you push the button, it will pull the pin high. When you release the button, the pin will stay high because there is nothing to pull it down. To solve that, add pull-down resistors (from the input pins to GND) of 1k to 100k value.
2. If it is a TTL 7408, they have built in pull-up resistors. That means the pins will float high, then pressing the switch will pull it high as well, so you can never get a 0. To solve that, the switches should go to ground.
3. You are missing a decoupling capacitor (ceramic cap between VCC and GND). This should be of ~100nF value.
4. You don't show your wiring, so you could have wired something up wrong.
5. On some larger breadboards, the power rails are not continuous, there's a gap in the middle of the board. It may be that you have wired your circuit over such a gap, so there are missing connections.